Terraform for Cloudflare without API Token
I'm trying to deploy Cloudflare resources with terraform. However the terraform provider for Cloudflare requires an API token from Cloudflare. Unfortunately API tokens need to be managed, and rotated occasionally.
So I was wondering is it possible to deploy Cloudflare resources programmatically with Terraform without using Cloudflare API tokens? I've read the docs including https://developers.cloudflare.com/fundamentals/ and https://developers.cloudflare.com/terraform/ so far and I can't find a way.
Does anyone know a way to do this, or a work around to do this perhaps with OIDC, SAML, or OAUTH?

As the documentation in your link states, you have an option of using either api_key, api_token or api_user_service_key

One of the ways I have found is using Hashicorp Vault as a secrets engine for minting Cloudflare Access service tokens.
This Vault plugin allows you to manage Cloudflare tokens.
